# Creating/updating array of objects in elasticsearch logstash output

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, logstash, elastic-stack

I am facing an issue using elastic search output with logstash. Here is my sample event

```
{
    "guid":"someguid",
    "nestedObject":{
        "field1":"val1",
        "field2":"val2"
    }
}
```

I expect the document with id to already be present in elasticsearch when this update happens.
Here is what I want to have in my elastic search document after 2 upserts:

```
{
    "oldField":"Some old field from original document before upserts."
    "nestedObjects":[{
        "field1":"val1",
        "field2":"val2"
        },
        {
        "field3":"val3",
        "field4":"val4"
        }]
}
```

Here is my current elastic search output setting:

```
elasticsearch {
    index => "elastictest"
    action => "update"
    document_type => "summary"
    document_id => "%{guid}"
    doc_as_upsert => true
    script_lang => "groovy"
    script_type => "inline"
    retry_on_conflict => 3
    script => "
    if (ctx._source.nestedObjects) {
    ctx._source.nestedObjects += event.nestedObject
    } else {
    ctx._source.nestedObjects = [event.nestedObject]
    }
    "
    }
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
response=>{"update"=>{"_index"=>"elastictest", "_type"=>"summary",
"_id"=>"64648dd3-c1e9-45fd-a00b-5a4332c91ee9", "status"=>400, 
"error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason"=>"failed to parse [event.nestedObject]", 
"caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception",
"reason"=>"unknown property [field1]"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be internally generated mapping in elasticsearch due to other documents with the same document_type with conflicting type on the field nestedObject. This caused elastic to throw a mapper parsing exception. Fixing this, fixed this issue.